# Operands in "int i = 0"

Tags: c, operands

I would like to ask if this short code:

```
int i = 0;
```

has 1 operand or 2? The `i` is an operand, but is `0` too? According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand), 0 shouldn't (or maybe I misunderstand). If 0 isn't operand, is it a constant or something?
If it is important, the code is in C99.

Comment: I cannot possibly see how the link you provided supports your claim. Quote relevant parts.

Comment: In section "Computer Science": "In computing, an operand is the part of a computer instruction which specifies what data is to be manipulated or operated on, while at the same time representing the data itself."

Comment: I think, that we are not manipulating or operating on `0`, just an assigment?

Comment: `=` is definitely operating on the `0`.

Comment: Assigning it is _certainly_ a _manipulation_.  It is also a _literal constant_; the two are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `int i = 0;`, `=` is not an operator. It's simply a part of the variable initializaton syntax. On the other hand, in `int i; i = 0;` it would be an operator.

Since `=` here is not an operator, there are no operands. Instead, `0` is the *initializer*.

Comment: I agree that it is a part of initialization, but claiming that it means that it is not an operator is pretty bold. Do you have any source to backup your claim?

Comment: @Arkku Can you link me to the revelant grammar? In `C11 6.7 Declarations 1` I found `init-declarator: \n declarator \n declarator = initializer`, which doesn't mention assingnment expressions. Instead, it mentions the symbol `=` directly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hmm, you may be right, I jumped straight to the section on initialization which begins with `initializer: assignment-expression`, but it does indeed seem that this is missing the `declarator =` part. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9

Comment: @Arkku That probably just means that an assignment can be an initializer, like in `int a; int b = a = 1;`.

Comment: In ancient C initializations were even done without the `=` sign. (e.g., `int i 0;` IIRC). The now public old UNIX sources use that. Can't quite remember why `=` was later made part of the syntax.

Comment: @PSkocik I'd say because unlike `int i 0;`, `int i = 0` doesn't look ugly. :)

Comment: @Broman Operator has to be a part of an expression. If there is no expression, there can't be any operators. It's similar to how `*` is not an operator in `int *x;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, that is correct, hence my original argument from the grammar is invalid. (Unrelated to this, I would still argue that the `i` and the `0` could be called operands, like they would be in something like `mov [rbp+4], 0`, but this is more of a general argument than anything based on C nomenclature.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Beauty's in the eyes of the beholder (I kind of like the distinct syntax actually) but there was a specific reason where it clashed w/ something else IIRC. I should've saved source I saw it in cuz I'm not having much luck trying to find it now.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm doing my best to falsify your claim at the moment, because this was really interesting. I have not found anything that supports that an operator cannot exist outside an expression, nor that there is no expression here.

Comment: BTW the original question is about _operands_, not operators. So one could argue that regardless of whether the `=` is called an operator in this context, there is still (at least conceptually) and "operation" happening (initializing `i` to `0`), and the operands would conceptually be the `i` and the `0`. (Then again, one could also argue that depending on the context the existence of this initialization might not necessarily result in any _actual_ "operation" being performed, e.g., it could be optimized away by the compiler.)

Comment: @Broman I'd also say you need an expr for an operator. Not that it matters much. It's just terminology. But operators do stuff, and declarations just declare something's somewhere, which for static-lifetime declaration doesn't involve a lot of doing (for locals, it does though. there it's basically like a combination of an empty declaration with an assignment operation).

Comment: @Broman To check if there is an expression here, check the grammar linked above. According to the grammar, the only expression here is the `0` itself. *"anything that supports that an operator cannot exist outside an expression"* That's not a solid argument, but `C11 6.5 Expressions 1` defines an expression as *"a sequence of operators and operands"*. It doesn't say that operators can't appear outside of expressions, but to me it seems to be implied.

Comment: @PSkocik Yeah, I'm reading and reading and I have to agree that an operator cannot exist without an expression. But I'm still not convinced that `int i = 0;` does not contain an expression, except for the trivial expression `0`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat See my above comment.

Comment: @Broman Well, an expression is a grammatical term, so you can just check if `int i = 0;` matches the grammar for an expression or not.

Comment: @Arkku Indeed, it depends on how you define an operand. I'm used to defining it as an argument of an operator. `C11 6.5 Expressions 1` *"An expression is a sequence of operators and operands"* is not a solid proof of that, but the standard doesn't seem to define 'an operand' anywhere.

Comment: Hmmm, this was a really tricky one and I'm perfectly aware that I'm on thin ice here, but I would argue that a *declarator* counts as an expression, and the reason you cannot find declarator in the grammar for expressions is the fact that ALL declarator are identifiers, and a single identifier IS an expression according to the grammar.

Comment: Oh, I found something that may prove what I said wrong. *"An identifier is a primary expression, provided it has been declared as designating an object"*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186146/discussion-between-broman-and-holyblackcat).

Comment: @PSkocik Please join the chat

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged the question as "C", one way to look at it is by reading the C standard. As pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54031063/204883), initialization (such as `int i = 0`) is not an expression in itself, and by a strict reading of the standard, the `=` here is not an operator *according to the usage of those terms in the standard*.

It is not as clear whether `i` and `0` are operands, however. On one hand, the C standard does not seem to refer to the parts of the initialization as operands. On the other hand, it doesn't define the term "operand" exhaustively. For example, one could interpret section 6.3 as calling almost any non-operator part of an expression an "operand", and therefore at least the `0` would qualify as one.

(Also note that if the code was `int i; i = 0;` instead, the latter `i` and the `0` would definitely both be operands of the assignment operator `=`. It remains unclear whether the intent of the question was to make a distinction between assignment and initialization.)

Apart from the C standard, you also refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand), in particular:

> In computing, an operand is the part of a computer instruction which specifies what data is to be manipulated or operated on, while at the same time representing the data itself.

If we consider the context of a "computer instruction", the C code might naively be translate to assembly code like `mov [ebp-4], 0` where the two operands would clearly be the `[ebp-4]` (a location where the variable called `i` is stored) and the `0`, which would make both `i` and `0` operands by this definition. Yet, in reality the code is likely to be optimized by the compiler into a different form, such as only storing `i` in a register, in which case zeroing it might become `xor eax, eax` where the `0` no longer exists as an explicit operand (but is the result of the operation). Or, the whole `0` might be optimized away and replaced by some different value that inevitably gets assigned. Or, the whole variable might end up being removed, e.g., if it is used as a loop counter and the loop is unrolled.

So, in the end, either it is something of a philosophical question ("does the zero exist as an operand if it gets optimized away"), or just a matter of deciding on the desired usage of the terms (perhaps depending on the context of discussion).

Answer (score 1):

> The `i` is an operand, but is `0` too? According to wikipedia, 0 shouldn't
>   (or maybe I misunderstand).

The question links to the Wikipedia page describing the term "operand" in a mathematical context.  This likely factors in to your confusion about whether the 0 on the right-hand side of the `=` is an operand, because in a mathematical statement of equality such as appears in the article, it is in no way conventional to consider `=` an operator.  It does not express a computation, so the expressions it relates are not operated upon.  *I.e.* they do not function as operands.

You have placed the question in C context, however, and in C, `=` can be used as an assignment operator.  This is a *bona fide* operator in that it expresses a (simple) operation that produces a result from two operands, and also has a side effect on the left-hand operand.  In an assignment statement such as

```
i = 0;
```

, then, both `i` and `0` are operands.

With respect to ...

> If 0 isn't operand, is it a constant or something?

... `0` standing on its own *is* a constant in C, but that has little to do with  whether it serves as an operand in any given context.  Being an operand is a way an expression, including simply `0`, can be *used*.  More on that in a moment.

Now it's unclear whether it was the intent, but the code actually presented in the question is very importantly different from the assignment statement above.  As the other answers also observe,

> ```
> int i = 0;
> ```

is a *declaration*, not a statement.  In that context, the `i` is the identifier being declared, the `0` is used as its *initializer*, and just as the `=` in a mathematical equation is not an operator, the `=` introducing an initializer in a C declaration is not an operator either.  No operation is performed here, in that no value computation is associated with this `=`, as opposed to when the same symbol is used as an assignment operator.  There being no operator and no operation being performed, there also are no operands in this particular line of code.